# python iterating list of dicts

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have a list of dictionaries that I am iterating over. I want to be able to pass the list to a container object, and then traverse the container by retrieving a tuple of the values of each dict as I iterate over it.

For example:

```
myDict = {"key1": "value1string", "key2": "value2string"}
myList = [myDict]

container = ContainerObj(myList)
for value1, value2 in container:
    print "value1 = %s, value2 = %s" % value1, value2
```

And I want the output to be:

```
"value1 = value1string, value2 = value2string"
```

How can I define the `__iter__` method in `ContainerObj` to accomplish this?

I tried doing the following which didn't work:

```
class ContainerObj(object):
    def __init__(self, listArg):
        self.myList = listArg
        self.current = 0
        self.high = len(self.myList)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.myList.__iter__()

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current >= self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            myDict = self.myList[self.current]
            self.current += 1
            return (
                    myDict.get("key1"),
                    myDict.get("key2")
            )
```

Comment: fixed, although that's a minor point. you understand what I am getting at...

Comment: Also I just checked:

>>> dict = {"a":5}
>>> mylist = [dict]
>>> mylist[0]
{'a': 5}

Unless you're commenting that is a `list` of one `dict` as opposed to multiple, which is an even more minor point.

Comment: Please don't override the builtin names (list, dict, etc). It will cause you pain later...or now.

Comment: I simply used those names for the purposes of the example -- they aren't the variable names I am using in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want are [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Usually you do this by using `yield` instead of `return` in a function. But in your case I think you could use itertools to help:

```
from itertools import chain
item_gen = chain(d.values() for d in my_dicts_list)
# Edit: Note that this will give you values continuously (not what you want), should have done
# item_gen = (d.values() for d in my_dicts_list)
```

To do this with a class you could do something like this:

```
class MyContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.the_list = my_list

    def __iter__(self):
        for d in self.the_list:
            yield d.values()
            # or:
            # yield (d.get("key1", None), d.get("key2", None))
```

Then you can use this object like any iterable:

```
my_con = MyContainer([{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}])
for val1, val2 in my_con:
    print "a = %s; b = %s" % (val1, val2)
```

Edit 1: Oops, realized I was returning items. You wanted just the values.

Also, you were essentially making generators yourself. Use the builtin functionality, it'll be easier and less painful. I highly suggest looking at the `itertools` module. There are also the `iterkeys`, `itervalues`, and `iteritems`methods of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To get output what is desired simply do like below.

```
t={'l':'t','t':'l'}

','.join('{}={}'.format(key, val) for key, val in t.items())

output = 'l=t,t=l'
```

Comment: I understand there are other ways of iterating this list. However, I am more interested in learning how to use the __iter__ function as 1. I am fairly new to python and am interesting in utilizing some of its more powerful functionality. and 2. I find the other mechanism to be cleaner.

Also, your example has `t` set to a `dict`. I am trying to iterate a `list` of `dicts`.